# shell for loop un expected token MAC terminal

Tags: macos, bash, shell

getting a unexpected token error, no idea why tried pretty much everything.

```
bash version `3.2.57(1)-release`

Count=31;
for (( i=1 ; i<=$Count ; i++ ))
do
 echo $i
done

'/script.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `
'/script.sh: line 3: `for (( i=1 ; i<=$Count ; i++ ))
```

Comment: Add to your question output of: `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Comment: Often a forgetten `' ") } fi done` or mixed `(}` `{)` will keep unnoticed by the shell until it sees another token. The comment (line 3) is actually related to the code not shown here. Or to a strange line-ending (\r or \r\n).

Comment: bash version is 3.2.57

Comment: i get similar error even when it try the following code:

Comment: for i in {1..100};
do
 echo $i;
done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove carriage returns from your script:

```
sed -i '' 's/\r$//' file.sh
```

Update:

```
sed -i '' $'s/\r//' file.sh
```

Comment: same error : command not founde 1: 
: command not founde 2: 
: command not founde 3: 
'/script.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `
'/script.sh: line 4: `for (( i=1; i<=$Count; i++ ))